# Convert Java.util.Calendar to org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime (for Android)

Tags: android, threetenbp

How to convert from Android Java Date and Calendar to threeten LocalDateTime

```
Calendar calTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calTime.getTime();

LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(date.getTime()/1000)
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalDateTime();
```

Fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is less than optimal.

## `LocalDateTime` has no zone/offset

Firstly, your use of `LocalDateTime` is inappropriate almost certainly. You are discarding valuable information about time zone or offset. The [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDateTime.html) class purposely has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, and therefore does *not* represent an actual moment, only a rough idea about possible moments over a range of 26-27 hours or so.

Instead use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` when dealing with actual moments on the timeline.

We only use `LocalDateTime` when:

- We do not know the zone.
- We intend multiple zones for a non-simultaneous moment (“all our factories around the world close at noon for lunch”).
- We are scheduling out into the future more that a few weeks and so we get might get hit by capricious politicians re-defining the time zone such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) with little notice. We use `LocalDateTime` for logic, and present to the user as a `ZonedDateTime` when generating a transient calendar.

## `DateTimeUtils` for conversions

Next, your conversion math is needless.

The [`DateTimeUtils`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class provides utility methods for conversions.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime( myCalendar ) ;
```

or…

```
Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant( myCalendar ) ;
```

P.S. Do not answer your Question inside the body text of the Question. Instead, post an actual Answer, and then accept it to close the Question.

Tips: For those wanting to use [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) in Android, see the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. And see [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).